# Trying to understand the physical intuition on finding/deriving effective rotation radii of a rigid body

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

This question is inspired from the answer of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/119576/how-does-separation-of-tracks-affect-the-acceleration-of-a-rolling-ball-on-the-t)

> If the rolling is assumed to be without slipping, we can solve the problem by conservation of energy:
>   $$ mg \Delta h = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 + \frac{1}{2} I \omega^2 \tag{*} \,,$$
>   with the relationship between $v$ and $\omega$ set by the spacing of the rods through the radius of contact during rolling.<sup>1</sup> 
>   You seek to determine the effective radius $r_{eff}$ of the rolling. For rods of diameter much less than the radius of the ball and spacing $d$ you can use $r_{eff}^2 = r^2 - (d/2)^2$. If you allow that the diameter of the rods is non-trivial, the geometry is a little more complicated.
>   In either case use $v = r_{eff}\omega$ in (*) and insert the appropriate moment of inertia ($\frac{2}{5}mr^2$ for a solid sphere), and you are home and dry.

The formula for the tracks such that each rail is equally spaced from the sphere of moment of inertia $I$(and assuming negligible diameter)is given by 
$$r_{eff}^2 = r^2 - (d/2)^2 \tag{**}$$

which is illustrated as [image]

Now it seems tempting that to generalise to the asymmetric case where the tracks are unequally spaced from the centre of the sphere will be derived as follows:

[image]

which by trigonometry and using similar triangles

$$x=\frac{an}{d(n-1)}$$

One obtains
$$r_{eff}=\sqrt{r^2-\left(\frac{d}{n}\right)^2}+\left(a-\frac{an}{d(n-1)}\right)$$

However, as I cannot find the general equation for a general rigid body's angular velocity dependence on effective radius (because I don't know the name of that equation, if any) for that allow one to model all possible cases of the Ball rolling down the track problem, I have no idea (at least for the symmetric case) why in terms of physical arguments the angular velocity must depend on the effective radius and why the effective radius must have the form shown in (**)?

> Or more simply, what are the physical rationale that justify that we can derive the formula (**) from trigonometry and how to generalise it to the asymmetric  track case with an arbitrary number of contact points?

Comment: It is the "rolling without slipping" condition that forces you to use an effective radius. The point of contact must have zero linear velocity at all times (otherwise it is slipping...). I think you've drawn the effective radius incorrectly in your diagram for the asymmetric rails if the rails are understood to be straight. I'm pretty sure that the effective radius should be measured perpendicular to the chord between the points of contact, because otherwise only one of the rails would fulfill the rolling without slipping condition.